# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after installing it alongside Windows

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I'm new to the Ubuntu OS and I want to be able to run it in ANY way I can.

I made a bootable USB (not persistent) to install Ubuntu. Followed the instructions in the install, had made a partition of 35 GB before, installed it with everything going smoothly. Restarted the computer and wasn't able to boot it. I looked it up and found that I had to turn off Secure Boot (did it) and use the Boot Repair tool, used it and nothing happened.

Also tried doing a live USB with persistence to at least be able to run Ubuntu in a 16 (or 32 GB) but is not kept persistent.

Does anyone have any suggestions or can provide help?

You can find my Boot-Repair report at the link below:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/25590048/

If anyone finds this and haven't found any solution, try this:

Just as MichaelBay suggested, make sure everything is set to UEFI, turn off Legacy. In BIOS options enable Secure Boot. Go to Security Tab and select Add file to Secure Boot(someting like that) then loop through the files that are shown and look for ubuntu file. Select it and save changes, restart computer and boot the Boot Options Menu(F12) and the file you jut added should be shown.

Comment: Can you please run Boot Repair again but do NOT apply any fix, just obtain the report and then [edit] the question and post it here?

Comment: Have you unplugged the USB? Serious question.

Comment: Restarted the computer before looking at this, edited in the report

Comment: @dibs Yes I have

Comment: Manufacturer installed Windows 10 is **always** in UEFI mode. You installed Ubuntu in Legacy/CSM. First of all, open UEFI settings and disable Legacy so as to prevent your USB from booting (and consequently installing) in the wrong mode.

Comment: Curious. I though I had enabled just UEFI. WIll read that and report.

Comment: Made it work. But was not because of that. As I said: I thought I had enabled just UEFI and I, indeed, did it. What I did different was that I had to turn Enable Secure Boot, go to Security Tab, went to the Secure Boot options> Add file to secure boot(something like that)>EFI>ubuntu>
Save changes, restarted machine>didn't boot instantly(even though the order is arranged) so I pressed F12> chose ubuntu and done.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work. But none of the post I found about creating it in UEFI worked(because I had already created it in UEFI). It is ineed importat that you verify that if you want to boot it in UEFI, you install it in UEFI.

What I did different was that I had to turn on Enable Secure Boot in BIOS

Go to Security Tab

Gent to the Secure Boot options

Add file to secure boot(something like that)>EFI>ubuntu> Save changes

Restarted machine didn't boot instantly(even though the order is arranged) so I 
pressed F12> chose ubuntu and done.

Comment: Is you machine an Acer, and is what you did "enable trust" on the ubuntu bootloader?

Comment: It is Acer. And I didn't understand the second question. You mean if I enabled Secure Boot? Yes I did.